# SQL Server single query memory usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to find out or at least estimate how much memory does a single query (a specific query) eats up while executing. There is no point in posting the query here as I would like to do this on multiple queries and see if there is a change over different databases. Is there any way to get this info?

Using SQL Server 2008 R2

thanks

Gilad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to take a look into DMV (Dynamic Management Views) and specifically into [sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365393.aspx). See for example this query (taken from [here](http://sql-kevin.blogspot.com/2010/08/sql-server-2008-query-memory-usage.html)):

```
DECLARE @mgcounter INT
SET @mgcounter = 1
WHILE @mgcounter <= 5 -- return data from dmv 5 times when there is data
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants) > 0
    BEGIN
             SELECT *
             FROM sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants mg
                         CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(mg.sql_handle) -- shows query text
             -- WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01' -- add a delay if you see the exact same query in results
             SET @mgcounter = @mgcounter + 1
    END
END
```

While issuing the above query it will wait until some query is running and will collect the memory data. So to use it, just run the above query and after that your query that you want to monitor.

Answer (score 6):

What do you mean by "how much memory a query eats up?", and why exactly do you want to know?

I don't think memory in SQL Server works the way you might imagine - memory management in SQL Server is an **incredibly** complex topic - you could easily write entire books about SQL Servers memory management.  I can't claim to know *that* much about SQL Servers memory management, but I do know that there is pretty much no useful information that you can extrapolate from knowing how much memory a single query uses up.

That said, if you did want to have a go at understanding whats going on with memory when you execute a query then I would probably start with looking at the buffer pool.  Nearly all memory in SQL Server is organised into 8KB chunks (the same size as a page) of memory that can be used to store anything from a data page or index page to a cached query plans.  The buffer pool is the main memory component in SQL Server - All 8KB chunks of memory not in use elsewhere remains in the buffer pool to be used as a cache for data pages.

Note that in order for a data page or index page to be used it must exist in memory - this means that if it doesn't already exist in memory elsewhere ready for use, a free buffer must be made available to ready the page in to.  The buffer pool serves both as a pool of "expendable" free buffers, and a cache of pages already present in memory.

You can examine whats in the buffer pool using DMVs, there is a suitable query listed on this page:

- [What's swimming in your bufferpool?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlperf/archive/2007/05/18/bufferpooldatapagesbreakdown.aspx)

By cleaning out your buffer pool using the command `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` (**DONT DO THIS ON A PRODUCTION SQL SERVER!!!**) and then executing your query, in theory the new pages that appear in the buffer pool should be the pages that were used in the last query.

This can give you a rough idea of the data and index pages used in a query, however doesn't cover other areas of SQL Server where memory is used, such as in the query plan cache, SQL Server Workers etc..

Like I said, SQL Server memory management is complex - If you really want to know more I recommend that you buy a book on SQL Server internals.

**Update:** You can also use the query statistics to view the aggregate performance statistics for a query including "physical reads" (pages read from the disk) and "logcal reads" (pages read from the buffer pool).  See [this page](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dmv-queries/find-queries-taking-most-memory/) for a suitable query.

This might also give you some more hints on how much memory a query is using, however beware - playing around I found queries that performed many more logical reads than they did physical reads, which as far as I can work out meant that they read the same pages over and over again, i.e. 100 logical reads != 100 pages used in the buffer pool.